# Why are my menu items difficult to click on an iPad?

Tags: css, ipad, menu

If you try to navigate on my website http://goo.gl/Pluy2 with an iPad you will notice that the horizontal menu doesn't react quite well. You need to push several times each menu item before something happens.

Would you know why the site reacts like that on an iPad? Is it something that can be fixed via CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the issue, but it could be a click event as opposed to a tap. To fix that, I think you could do

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).bind('tap');
});
```

or some variation of that, because I don't know if that works or not. Basically jQuery tap events are designed for mobile browsers and human fingers. It may or may not solve the issue, but it's worth a shot.

There are probably JS solutions as well, but I'm most comfortable with jQuery, so if you don't use jQuery on your site, you might look into alternative methods to mine.